# Sticking Elements (Sub Menu) on web page issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create a sub-menu on my website. I have the menu created, but I want it to stick; its primary purpose would be to link to other parts of the same page, but when I scroll the menu gets left behind.

I built the menu using The Jupiter plugin. We already have a universal navigation bar across all pages, and this sticks to the top always.

My question is: how can I make it stick as I scroll down the page?

I'm using WordPress Bakery aswell. I can provide screenshots or more info if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post snippets of your HTML and CSS for what you've already implemented? Or a link to the page for us to inspect?

Comment: Hello Tessa, here is the code for the menu tab I'd like to implement. : [vc_row][vc_column][mk_header align="center" hover_styles="4" menu_location="third-menu" logo="false" burger_icon="false" search_icon="false" woo_cart="false"][/vc_column][/vc_row]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using position:sticky in the CSS?

https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/

Comment: How would I implement that on WordPress? Considering its technically part of Wordpress Bakery.

Comment: I've not used it myself but there's a guide here that may help?
https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/learning-more/custom-css/